# Array of Arrays to Array of Objects JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

This particular challenge calls for me to convert an array of arrays (is there a term for this?) into an array of objects, like so:

```
[[['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']],
[['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']]]
```

into:

```
[{firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Blow', age: 42, role: 'clerk'},
{firstName: 'Mary', lastName: 'Jenkins', age: 36, role: 'manager'}]
```

Here's my code, so far:

```
function transformEmployeeData(array) {
var object={};
for (var i = 0; i < array.length;i++){
    var newArray = array[i];
    object[i] = newArray[1];
    object[newArray[0]] = object[i];
    newArray.push(object);
    delete object[i];
    }
return object;
}

var myArray= [['firstName','Joe'],['lastName','Blow'],['age', 42], ['role','clerk']];
transformEmployeeData(myArray);
```

It seems to work great, until I add another nested array with a second (or third, or fourth, which is the whole point of the thing) employee's data.

I'm sure it has something to do with the loop, but I can't spot it.

Help appreciated!

Comment: Create a nested loop that iterates over `newArray` and sets the values from the even indexes to the props from the odd indexes. Btw, `object[i] = newArray[1]` - this line is redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a new object *inside* the loop, so that you're creating a new object each time rather than just reassigning properties of the same object - you were pushing the same object into the array multiple times. (I'm not sure why you were using `delete` - you don't need it.)

So something like this:

```js
function transformEmployeeData(data) {
  var result = []                              // new array to hold transformed data
  var key, value
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {      // loop over employees
    var employee = {}                          // new object for current employee
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { // loop over current employee details
      key = data[i][j][0]                      // extract property key name
      value = data[i][j][1]                    // and value
      employee[key] = value                    // add property to object
    }
    result.push(employee)                      // add new object to array
  }
  return result
}

var input = [[['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']],
[['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']]]

console.log( transformEmployeeData(input) )
```

Or if you want to use some array functions like [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) you can "simplify" the code:

```js
function transformEmployeeData(data) {
  return data.map(function(employee) {
    return employee.reduce(function(a, c) {
      a[c[0]] = c[1]
      return a
    }, {})
  })
}

var input = [[['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']],
[['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']]]

console.log( transformEmployeeData(input) )
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer was by far the most helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) and [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
let arrayOfArrays = [[['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']],
[['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']]];

let arrayOfObjects = arrayOfArrays.map(array => array.reduce((acc, val) => {
  acc[val[0]] = val[1];
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(arrayOfObjects);
```

Comment: `array.reduce((acc, [k, v]) => ({ [k]: v, ...acc }))`

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this answer until after I edited my own answer to include a map/reduce solution. +1.

Comment: OP cannot deal with nested loops, and the community comes with a map/reduce solution. Does one seriously think OP would be able to learn from it?

Comment: @zerkms We can only hope so; that's why providing documentation links is good.

Comment: And @nnnnnn I did the same thing; just deleted my answer :/

Comment: @zerkms As a member of the community, I provide answers for the community, not just for the OP.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen `s/provide answers/write code for free/`. Code-only answers are rarely useful.

Comment: @zerkms It's not a code only answer. I provide links to the relevant pages in (what I assume is considered to be) the canonical documentation for all things JavaScript. Do you want me to reproduce that documentation here? As it stands, for a question titled *"Array of Arrays to Array of Objects JS"*, I think my post answers the question, and  is both correct and idiomatic JavaScript. If you think this is not the case, or if you think my answer violates any of SO's terms, feel free to flag or vote to delete.

Comment: I don't think it's wrong (it's a decent piece of js, indeed), what I mean is that - it's not reusable. Any variation (to the task conditions) would make the answer useless for a less experienced developer.

Comment: @zerkms - I don't like to just throw beginners in the deep end, which is why I often show a more "basic" old-school loop-based solution first, and then expand on that with a more "advanced" array function version. That way somebody interesting in learning (which I assume the OP here is given they made an attempt to code it themselves) can look at the parallels between the two solutions, and follow the links to the doco to understand in more detail.

Comment: @zerkms can you try post your answer? It seems like you know the BEST way to do it. Please post your  answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution using `forEach` Array object method

```
    var array = [[['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']],
    [['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']]];

    transformEmployeeData(array);

    function transformEmployeeData(array){
      var employees = [];
      array.forEach(function(employee,index){
        var employeeObj = {};
        employee.forEach(function(data,key){
          employeeObj[data[0]] = data[1];
        });
        employees.push(employeeObj);
      });
      return employees;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With Object.fromEntries, a one liner

```js
let input = [[['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']],
[['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']]]

console.log(input.map(elem => Object.fromEntries(elem)))
```